# Sencha Touch Button - Pause till reveal

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2

I want to delay showing a sencha touch button element for several seconds. How would I do this?

I have the following [item]

```
                        xtype: 'button',
                        align: 'right',
                        hidden: false,
                        html: 'Go!'
```

How would I delay showing that for example 10 seconds?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be a better practice to use `Ext.util.DelayedTask`

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following snippet of code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('MyPanel').add({
        xtype:'button',
        align:'right,
        html('Go!')
    });        
}, 10000);
```

That is assuming you have a panel or container with an 'id' config set to 'MyPanel' as the parent of the button you want to add.
You can execute this in one of your controllers for instance.

Another way, if your button was already declared like you mentioned in your question:

```
{
     xtype: 'button',
     align: 'right',
     hidden: false,
     html: 'Go!',
     id:'MyButton'
}
```

is to change the 'hidden' property in the setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('MyButton').setHidden(false);
}, 10000);
```

Again, you can execute this in one of your controllers for instance.